# Test Result File(.trx) Counters does not match detailed test data

Tags: c#, vstest, trx

I encountered a strange result with a recent test result ran with vstest.console.exe where I would have Not Executed as Outcome of some of my tests but the counters would not reflect these results.

The actual "Counters" line is :

```
<Counters total="84" executed="78" passed="78" failed="0" error="0" timeout="0" aborted="0" inconclusive="0" passedButRunAborted="0" notRunnable="0" notExecuted="0" disconnected="0" warning="0" completed="0" inProgress="0" pending="0" />
```

As you can see, the "total" counter and the "executed" counter are not the same. When looking into the tests outcome I can find that the outcome of those missing tests is "NotExecuted"

Here is the example :

```
<UnitTestResult executionId="b2be72ea-9196-4910-88f8-999fd342fef7" testId="717d6c19-e8ba-bf3d-44c5-0fe541873ab5" testName="MyTest" computerName="MyComputer" duration="00:00:04.1010226" startTime="2017-07-26T11:24:00.5455072-04:00" endTime="2017-07-26T11:24:04.6392676-04:00" testType="13cdc9d9-ddb5-4fa4-a97d-d965ccfc6d4b" outcome="NotExecuted" testListId="8c84fa94-04c1-424b-9868-57a2d4851a1d" relativeResultsDirectory="b2be72ea-9196-4910-88f8-999fd342fef7">
```

Here I would expect the result to be :

```
total="84" executed="78" passed="78" notExecuted="6"
```